# c# Bluetooth SerialPort reconnect

Tags: c#, arduino, bluetooth, serial-port

I am working on an arduino project using the bluetooth `module HC-06`. I found out that I can use the `serialPort` in a `c# WinForms` application το connect the module with my laptop ( having the already paired from bluetooth settings ) .

**My problem** is that when the bluetooth module gets out of range or gets powered down. **It does not reconnect with the application**. Plus I get not exceptions thrown. It seems like the application still thinks there is a connection.

**I've checked that** the 'COM5' that I am connecting to it remains open after the module is powered down. I've also tried to implement a timer function but no luck with that.

I'm quite new with that and I've searched enough but I could not understand what is going on or how to work around it

```
int count = 0;
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            serialPort1.PortName = "COM5";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;

            try
            {
                if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
                    serialPort1.Open();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
           // serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);

        }

        
        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SerialPort spl = (SerialPort)sender;
                Console.WriteLine(count++.ToString() + spl.ReadLine());
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: it is not good idea to use Serial Ports (vCOM) to communicate with your Bluetooth device. Use Bluetooth API (RFCOMM) instead. You can use 32feet or Bluetooth Framework for that if you do not want to spend time to learn Bluetooth API.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I've tried `32feet.net`. It seriously feels easier. I have not mastered it yet but I have already solved enough problems. Thank you for your suggestion, I will post an answer for future readers